# Is it possible to create a shareable embed link from an organisational One Drive account using Microsoft's Graph API?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I was wondering if you can create a shareable embed link from an organisational One Drive account using Microsoft's Graph API?

I have found this link: 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createlink

However embeddable link only work for personal One Drive accounts. This seems strange that they would restrict this feature in this way. Is there away around this?

Thanks, 
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

The keypoint for your question is **Information security**.

Theoretically, we can create a shareable embed link from an organisational One Drive account using Microsoft's Graph API. But due to the **enterprise security restrictions / rules of confidentiality**, the createLink cannot be called by Graph API for most organizations. This is **normal behavior** but not **strange** which you pointed. **Information security is important.**

If we use an organisational One Drive account to call the Graph API, we may get the following response. It have state the feature has been disabled.

> "message": "The feature has been disabled. Please contact your admin
>   to get it enabled.",

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, this does not answer my question. I understand the importance of security, however, would still like to know if it is possible to create a shareable embed link from an organisational One Drive account.

Comment: I have answer your question. Theoretically, it is possible. You must sure you have enable corresponding permission. I am not sure where to disable/enable. Normal,  this is controred by the IT, not dev. So the question have turned to IT pro issue but not dev issue. Trial O365 account and Graph Explorer cannot test everything. Some API/Case need the real Production env to test

Comment: I have tested the createlink in OneDrive for Business UI, it works. So theoretically, the API should also works without the limitation. Need to check with some IT pro how to disable the limitation. Before the enable operation done, the API won't work. Organisation care IT security then personal.

Comment: Could you explain to me how to do this?